# Format differently specific letter in a CATextLayer?

Tags: ios, coding-style, catextlayer

Is that possible?

If not with CATextLAyer, then how can I do that?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're talking about? The answer almost certainly is "two CATextLayers" (or two UILabels, or CoreText, or hand drawing).

Comment: hey, thats exactly what i did. i hoped i will be able to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSMutableAttributedString in CATextLayer. You can specify different attributes like color, font to different parts of string.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to break the word to letters and combine it back with 3 different text layers.
I will try to post the function i have build for others who needs it.